# what does vmstat "r" mean?

Tags: vmstat

I'm recently started studying RHEL. But I'm not sure, what does vmstat column "r" mean?

1. does it include kernel and user thread? or only kernel thread?
2. does vmstat command read /proc/stat or traversal /proc//stat?

Because for AIX, I know are response for only kernel thread (kernel thread or kmt thread). But for RHEL, the man page only show " r: The number of processes waiting for run time."

Comment: Does [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1160343 "How to read Vmstat output") help? And as for your 2nd question: ```strace(1)``` says yes, it does read ```/proc/stat```.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think you are right. strace says it open /proc/stat ..